# Primer formulario con django no lo renderiza por un if no cerrado

Tags: python, django

la verdad estoy aprendiendo django y intente hacer un formulario muy simple para la practica la verdad, y al buscar no me renderiza no lo hace por que supuestamente no esta cerrado un if en html siendo que en el codigo le tengo un endif y en el syntax me sale "Etiqueta no cerrada en la línea 7: 'if'. Buscando uno de: endif"

```
<html>

<body>
   
   <p>Estas buscando: <strong>{{query}}</strong></p>

   {% if articulos %}

       <p>Articulos encontrados: {{articulos|length}} articulos</p>

       <ul>

           {% for articulos in articulos %}

               <li>
                   {{articulos.nombre}}
               </li>

           {% endfor %}

       </ul>

   {% else %}

       <p>no existe el articulo buscado</p>

   {& endif %}



</body>

</html>
```

ademas pongo lo que tengo el views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from gestionPedidos.models import Articulos
# Create your views here.

def busqueda_productos(request):

    return render(request, "Busqueda_productos.html")
    def buscar(request):
    #CONDICIONAL PARA SABER SI EN EL TEXT SE HA INTRODUCIDO ALGO
    if request.GET["prd"]:
        producto=request.GET["prd"]
        #FILTRO PARA BUSCAR EN BBDD
        articulos=Articulos.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=producto)

        return render(request, "Resultados_busqueda.html", {"articulos":articulos, "query":producto})
        


    else:
        mensaje="No haz introducido nada"

    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

y el html de la busqueda la verdad es super simple, y no es nada complicado es un input tipo text y un input tipo submit

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Busqueda de productos</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="/buscar/" method="GET">
    
        <input type="text" name="prd">

        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    
    
    
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tienes puesto `{& endif %}`. ¿ No será `{% endif %}` ?

Comment: verdad muchas gracias